# Does Magento have an existing extension that works with SAP

Tags: magento, sap-erp

We run SAP ECC 6.0 basis version 702, and are integrating with Magento for order management. I know that SBOeConnect :eCommerce Integrated with SAP Business One ERP extension exists, but I do not know if this works with our SAP installation.

(SAP ECC 6 and Business One are two very different beasts.)

Has anyone experience with integration the two systems?

Does the extention support SAP ECC 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know that is the only extension. I would recommend [contacting](http://www.sboeconnect.com/Contact-for-Magento-sap-business-one-connector.html) them to ask if it supports your version of SAP.

The other option would be to build a custom module. Using the APIs and a cron job you can setup automatic push/pull events to sync data or tie it to an event observer for an action like a new transaction. There are obviously a lot of variables depending on what you specifically want to do.

Comment: I will confirm the answer once I get feedback from the vendor

Comment: Great. Most Magento/ERP integrations end up being custom, so don't be too disappointed if they don't support it. Most clients use systems no one has ever heard of. :)

Comment: I am giving you the answer acceptance instead of my own answer below :)